# typescript and vuejs export interface reach

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

hello i have a problem i have an auth module i want to access the value which is interface in this file from another vue file how can i do that

What I really want to do is to access name, surname and email information.

```
export interface User {
 name: string;
 surname: string;
 email: string;
}

export interface ExUserAuthInfo {
 user: User;
 isAuthenticated: boolean;
}

 @Module
 export default class ExAuthModule extends VuexModule implements ExUserAuthInfo {
 user = {} as User;
 isAuthenticated = !!ExJwtService.getAccessToken();

 get currentUser(): User {
 return this.user;
 }

 get isUserAuthenticated(): boolean {
return this.isAuthenticated;
 }
```

Comment: A function cannot return an interface, only a type. Try changing your definition of User from an `interface` to a `type`.

Comment: Can you clarify what's the problem? @Stitt No, this doesn't make sense, types and interfaces are interchangeable in most cases in TS